Axioms Underpinning Game Theory
I am currently working on a survey paper focused on the foundations of game theory, particularly the axiomatic underpinnings that have shaped its development. I am keen to explore seminal works and influential papers that delve into the core axioms and theoretical frameworks of game theory.
Could you please recommend essential readings or landmark papers that have significantly contributed to the understanding and formulation of the axioms in game theory? I am particularly interested in works that provide a deep dive into the theoretical aspects and foundational principles.
Thank you in advance for your recommendations and insights!

The development of non-cooperative game theory wasn't primarily shaped by axiomatic underpinnings.

I'd suggest to have a look at http://brandlf.com/publications/nash/ and the references therein.

This was the paper that inspired me to write the survey!
